# Office 365 web apps in iframe inside aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, sharepoint, office365, x-frame-options

Well am trying to open a word document from office 365 inside my aspx page.
The url is included in an iframe,however the page keeps throwing an error message "This content cannot be displayed in a frame".
example code:

```
 <iframe width="700" height="700"  src='https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={13438738-FBFF-4F32-A680-4BF6D47F7682}&action=default'></iframe>
```

I have tried the following but with no luck:

1. Add `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />` to SharePoint master page
2. Allow external iframes in **HTML Field Security** in office 365 site settings.
3. Add the office 365 SharePoint to trusted sites in internet explorer and enabling **display mixed content**
4. Add IHttpModule to my asp.net web application to adding headers for the X-Frame-Options  `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");`
5. Deploying `Ventigrate.Shared.PermissiveXFrameHeader` feature on the office 365 SharePoint site

The thing is I have added

> Ignore X-frame headers extension

to my google chrome and I was able to open the word document in google chrome only.

Also if I have change the action inside the url from **default** to **interactivepreview** the page will open in IE.

Nevertheless there is no extension for IE,but if there is a solution in google chrome that means there is a possibility to make it work for IE.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the page that refuses to be display in the iFrame is a login page such as login.microsoft.com? Such login pages cannot be iFramed for security reasons...

Comment: Nope it is not a login page. I've already checked.Because I can open the url in a new tab with no issues.